# Why is this expression independent of the choice of frame?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Reference: Wells- Differential analysis on complex manifolds p.69

Consider a complex vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$.

Let $\mathscr{E}(E)$ denote the collection of smooth sections and let $\mathscr{E}^k$ denote the smooth $k$-forms on $X$ and let $\mathscr{E}^k(E)$ denote smooth $k$-forms on $E$. Then, we have an isomorphism $\mathscr{E}^k\otimes_{C^\infty} \mathscr{E}(E)\cong \mathscr{E}^p(E)$.

Let's denote the image of $\phi\otimes \xi$ under the isomorphism by $\phi\cdot \xi$ for $\phi\in \mathscr{E}^k$ and $\xi\in \mathscr{E}(E)$.

Let $U$ be open in $X$ and $f=\{e_1,...,e_r\}$ be a frame for $E$ over $U$.

Then, we have a local representation for an $E$-valued $k$-form $\xi$ (locally defined on $U$) given by $(\xi^1(f),...,\xi^r(f))$, defined by the relation $\xi=\sum_{\rho=1}^r \xi^\rho(f)\cdot e_\rho$.

Namely, let $x\in U$ and let $(\omega_1,....,\omega_s)$ be a frame for $\wedge^k T^*(X)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ at $x$.

Then, we can write $\xi(x)=\sum_{\rho,j} \phi_{j\rho}(x)\omega_j(x)\otimes e_\rho(x)$ where the $\phi_{j\rho}$ are uniquely determined $C^\infty$ functions defined near $x$.

I'm fine with what illustrated above, but I don't get the next line:

"Let $\xi^k=\sum_j \phi_{j\rho}\omega_j$, and it is easy to check that the differential form $\xi^\rho$ so determined is independent of the choice of frame $(\omega_1,...,\omega_s)$."

I think it should be $\xi^\rho$ at first instead of $\xi^k$, am I correct? And of course from the definition of $\xi^\rho$, it only depends on the choice of $\{e_1,...,e_r\}$. So there is nothing to check here, but why the author wrote "it is easy to check..."?

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like there are several typos. In the second "paragraph" you should have $\mathscr E^k$, not $\mathscr E^p$. Yes, you're right that it should be $\xi^\rho$, of course. And he's just saying that the forms $\xi^\rho(f)$ are (locally) well-defined, depending on the choice of frame $f$. There really is not need to go down to a basis for the $k$-forms, agreed.